# Autofill function: read XML file and autofill textboxes using c#

Tags: c#, xml

I have an application for managing and accounting a company. I save all customers in an XML file. Now I want to autofill the "Surname" and "Forename" textboxes if the "CustNo" already exists. For this I use this code:

```
private void txtKNrNew_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(path + "\\save.xml");
        int CustNos;

        if (Int32.TryParse(txtKNrNew.Text, out CustNos))
        {
            var xmlNodeExist = "Buchhaltung/Customers/CustNo";
            var CustNoExist = xdoc.XPathSelectElements(xmlNodeExist).FirstOrDefault(x => (int)x == CustNos);
            var SurnameNode = "Buchhaltung/Customers/Surname";
            var ForenameNode = "Buchhaltung/Customers/Forename";
            var surnames = xdoc.XPathSelectElements(SurnameNode).FirstOrDefault(x => (int)x == CustNos);
            var forenames = xdoc.XPathSelectElements(ForenameNode).FirstOrDefault(x => (int)x == CustNos);

            if (CustNoExist != null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("not null");
            }
        }
    }
```

If I now type in some numbers in the textbox, there comes this error up:

> Input string was in incorrect format.

I don't know why this error comes up because in VS2012 there is no error. Only if I type something in the textbox the error appears. Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 1):

It seems the error is coming in this line :

```
var CustNos = int.Parse(txtKNrNew.Text);
```

May be you have some spaces between the numbers or decimal point like this : 122,999. Which will result parsing the string to int to fail.

What you can do is to try to parse whatever the user type in the textbox.

for example;

```
int CustNos ;
    if (int.TryParse(txtKNrNew.Text, out CustNos ))
    {
      // do what you want with CustNos 

    }
    else
    {
        // Display Error Message to user

    }
```

Comment: I just have even-numbers. So I have to put the part with `var surnames = xdoc.XPathSelectElements(SurnameNode).FirstOrDefault(x => (int)x == CustNos);
    var forenames = xdoc.XPathSelectElements(ForenameNode).FirstOrDefault(x => (int)x == CustNos);` in the `if(){}`?

Comment: put this in the if var SurnameNode = "Buchhaltung/Customers/Surname";
    var ForenameNode = "Buchhaltung/Customers/Forename";
    var surnames = xdoc.XPathSelectElements(SurnameNode).FirstOrDefault(x => (int)x == CustNos);
    var forenames = xdoc.XPathSelectElements(ForenameNode).FirstOrDefault(x => (int)x == CustNos);

    if (CustNoExist != null)
    {
        txtSurnameNew.Text = surnames.ToString();
        txtForenameNew.Text = forenames.ToString();
    }

Comment: I did an edit. This is what I have now. The error occures at `FirstOrDefault`